# How to parse date from Datepicker in UTC format?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-date

I want from user to pick a date and I want to set this date in ParseObject (I'm using Parse.com). Column in ParseObject is type Date and it is in same format as SimpleDateFormat below. But from DatePicker I will get just year, month and day. Those attributes are also in wrong format. I also need exact time.

Is there any way how to return Date from Datepicker in exact same format?

```
alertDialogDateBtn?.setOnClickListener {
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()

            val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'")
                    chosenDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(year.toString() + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1).toString() + "-" + dayOfMonth.toString())
                }, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE))
                    dpd.show()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but this worked for me :)

```
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }
        };
        fromDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(ViewActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your date coming from `DatePicker` to this function 
and your pattern from date picker selected date should be like this

> yyyy-mm-dd

```
public static String changeDateTimeFormat(String inputString) {
    Log.i(">>inputDate", "changeDateFormat: " + inputString);
    String[] date1 = new String[1];
    String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String outputPattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;
    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(inputString);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;

}
```

and this will return you the exact UTC date format you need